# unable to set email body font in mutt

Tags: linux, fonts, mutt

I am sending Data as in display form of Table to some gmail users. I want to set font type & font size while sending mail so that it will get displayed in proper format in receivers gmail view

need to set font = courier new

I am using : Redhat5_elx64 + mutt-1.4.2.2
sample o/p data at receivers end is as follows

+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Sales                   |   30 |    3 |   22 |    0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Production              |  235 |   65 |   86 |    2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Marketing               |   28 |   14 |   30 |    0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Advertisement           | 1739 |  528 | 1428 |   41 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 4):

There is no possibility to set the font in mutt. Email is plain text, it uses the font the receiver prefers to read his/her emails with. However, you can send your mail as HTML. Then you can use CSS to select a font preference.

When you write HTML you need to select the proper content type. The default is `text/plain`. Before sending the HTML mail, use the `edit-type` command (default shortcut `Ctrl+t`) and change the content type to `text/html`.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply. I solve the issue with use of perl language